# WSL win bash For command replace substring (former extention)

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using a program that creates one image type from another using a command line that calls it. I do like that:

for FILE in *.bmp; do (my-path-to-app).exe (program tasks) "$FILE" "$FILE.png"

The result is Myimage.bmp.png

Obviously I want the end result to be from Myimage.bmp to Myimage.png and not myimage.bmp.png. So how do I remove the .bmp before? Do I need to specify some trimming before the DO or after? I cant get this right

Comment: The bash command worked for u??? :O Are you in Linux/wsl or in Windows? windows batch and cmd scripting is way different than bash so plz be clear so we can help you. btw in windows for loops u can suppress the original extension and overwrite with `%%~dpn0.png`

Comment: I do these commands in windows bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with :

```
for FILE in *.bmp; do echo "$FILE" "${FILE%bmp}png"; done
```

`${FILE%bmp}` removes `bmp` from the end of `"$FILE"`

Comment: So simple yet evasive, thats what I was trying to get corrected for awhile, thanks!